# Call alias using a Python Script

Tags: python, macos, alias

I'm writing a python script that utilizes Ureka (a distribution of different astronomy packages).  In order to run any Ureka's packages, the user must first initialize Ureka by typing "ur_setup" in the terminal.  It turns out "ur_setup" is an alias for the following command:

```
'eval `/Users/rem/.ureka/ur_setup -csh \!*`'
```

How would I be able to include this in my python script and have it work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `import subprocess; subprocess.check_call("ur_setup", shell=True)` (You need the shell here to expand the alias)

Comment: You can use subprocess to call the command without the alias as well, but I would stick with it unless you need to be able to modify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [os.execv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execv) if you need to take over the running process else use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ureka, but for running any expression or command using python, you can certainly use the os module.

```
    import os
    os.system('eval `/Users/rem/.ureka/ur_setup -csh \!*`')
```

This Should work.

Comment: I get the following error when I tried this:
    sh: setenv: command not found

Comment: Just put this as your first line. #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: Try manually to run the command eval `/Users/rem/.ureka/ur_setup -csh \!*`
and see if you get any error or not.

Comment: Try to run ur_setup from a terminal to check that is working fine.
 if it is then change ur command to  os.system("ur_setup")